# Mutliple sessions on commit status/ aurora_redo_log_flush event in AWS Aurora 2.11.1 - MySQL 5.7

Tags: performance, mysql-5.7, amazon-rds-aurora

Our database runs on Aurora 2.11.1 - MySQL 5.7 and we have enabled performance insights.

It's usually runs in between 15 to 50 sessions at a given time. According to the performance insights around 20 - 30 sessions always wait on auroa_redo_log_flush event.

When we check from the backend it shows as above 20 - 30 sessions on the state **'delayed commit ok initiated'**.

How to figure out what are these sessions waiting on aurora_redo_log_flush or 'delayed commit ok initiated'.  In the documentation it just mentions that redo_log_flush is data is waiting to be flushed to the storage, but we need to identify what are the sessions which contribute to this redo_log_flush event ?